# Does the diophantine equation $ax^2+by^2=cz^2+d$ always have solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Let $a,b,c,d,x,y,$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$  where $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are constants but d is allowed to be zero .

$ax^2+by^2=cz^2+d$

First example :

when $a=b=c=1 $ and $d=0$ we have  the equation : $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which I know its general solution .

Second example:

$a=1 ,b=4,c=1$ and $d=0$ we have the equation : $x^2+4y^2=z^2$ . it has solutions.

one solution of it  is: $x=3,y=2,$ and $z=5$

Third example:

$a=2 ,b=3,c=1$ and $d=0$ we have the equation : $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$ .

this example I tried to find solutions among small numbers but I didn't find any solution.

So does $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$ have solutions but I didn't find any ?

or is there proof that $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$ doesn't have any solution?

Comment: gcd-type constraints will come in e.g. $4x^2+4y^z = 4z^2+1$ would have no solution, but otherwise I can't see anything stopping this.

Comment: Does the trivial solution $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$ not count for $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$?

Comment: @MartinØdegaard No because solutions $\in \mathbb{N}$ so solutions start from one.

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar But you said "Let $a,b,c,d,x,y,$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$" and later on had " $d=0$" so presumably your $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$ or was that a mistake?

Comment: @MartinØdegaard  Sorry I will correct my mistake

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246669/does-the-diophantine-equation-ax2by2-cz2d-always-have-solutions

Comment: Typo @TeresaLisbon ?

Comment: @EverywhereDense Oh yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: everything you might want is in Dickson (1939)  Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers. There are universal indefinite ternary quadratic forms; one requirement is that the form represent zero, but that is not enough. Dickson and his students found all such forms, up to $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalence

Comment: If $x=y$ then the equation can be reduced to Generalized Pell's equation $X^2-c(a+b)Y^2=d(a+b).$

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1390537_number_representation_using_polynomials

Comment: @individ Thank you very  much and your blog is really great because it contains many things about diophantine equations and number theory...

but please I want you when it is convenient to you to make example here on mathstack using the method in your blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$ actually has no solution for positive integers $x,y,z$.

Assume the smallest solution of $(x,y,z)$ (with minimal $z$) is $(r,s,t)$. Consider $\mod 8$, as $2x^2+ 3y^2\equiv 0,2,3,4,5,6 \pmod{8}$ and $z^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod{8}$, we can see $z^2 \equiv 0,4 \pmod{8}$, implies that $z$ is even. Let $z=2p$, then $2x^2+3y^2=4p^2$, which also implies $y$ to be even. Let $y=2q$, then $2x^2+12q^2=4p^2$, which becomes $x^2+6q^2=2p^2$, implying $x$ is also even. Let $x=2r$, then the equation becomes $4r^2+6q^2=2p^2$, which is $2r^2+3q^2=p^2$. Therefore, $(r,q,p)$ is also a solution. However, $p<z$, which means $(r,q,p)$ is a smaller solution, which contradicts the first statement. Therefore, there are no solutions for $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: $2x^2 + 3y^2 = z^2\quad$ has no non-zero  real solutions

Comment: @poetasis That is obviously not true.

Comment: @ Servaes
 You are right. I ignored $(0,0,0)#

Comment: @poetasis There are infinitely many real solutions for the equation for obvious reasons. What I have proven is just nonzero integer solutions (which can be applied to nonzero rational solutions)

Comment: A mod $3$ argument shows $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$ implies $3\mid\gcd(x,y,z)$, which gives the same contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This is the partial solution.

$ax^2+by^2-cz^2=d\tag{1}$
Substitute $ x=1, y=pt+1, z=qt+1$ to above equation.
$p,q$ are arbitrary.

If $a+b=c+d$ then we get $t = \large\frac{-2(bp-cq)}{-cq^2+bp^2}.$
If $bp^2-cq^2=\pm1$, we can get the integral solution $(x,y,z).$
Thus, equation $bp^2-cq^2=\pm1$ is reduced to Pell's equation $X^2-bcY^2=\pm b\tag{2}.$
If equation $(2)$ has a solution , then  equation $(1)$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions.

In particular, let $b=1$ then if $c$ is not a perfect square, Pell's equation $X^2-cY^2=1$ always has  infinitely many distinct integer solutions.

Example for $(a,b,c,d)=(4,1,2,3): p^2-2q^2 = 1.$
$(x,y,z)=(1, 7, 5),(1, 239, 169),(1, 8119, 5741),(1, 275807, 195025)$...

Example for $(a,b,c,d)=(14, 1, 13, 2): p^2-13q^2 = 1.$
$(x,y,z)=(1, 2194919, 608761),(1, 3698003921039, 1025641750321)$...